# Inside our SharePoint online tenant, is there a way to view all the Nintex workflows for all the sites, or at-least for a site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, administration, nintex

I am working on a SharePoint online tenant for a new customer, now the customer is using Nintex workflow, but I am trying to know how many Nintex workflows they have.

Now if I go a list >> I will get the Nintex button >> if I click on it I can view the Nintex workflows linked to that list, as follow:

[image]

But my question is, if there is a way to view all the Nintex workflows for all the site collections? or atleast for each site?

**EDIT**. this is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of all Nintex workflows in your tenant using:

1. Nintex Hawkeye
2. PowerShell

Check this thread for more information & PowerShell script: [How can I find all the workflows in my O365 SharePoint tenant using PowerShell](https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-Office-365-Forum/How-can-I-find-all-the-workflows-in-my-O365-SharePoint-tenant/m-p/92319)

Comment: can not i get these using the UI?

Answer (score -1):

Go to site settings >> Workflow Inventory

```
/_layouts/15/NintexWorkflow/WorkflowGallery.aspx
```

You can find this option under site settings >> Nintex workflow

[image]

In case you cannot access the Workflow-Inventory-page , please go to this URL
[Unable to access Workflow Inventory page](https://community.nintex.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Unable-to-access-Workflow-Inventory-page/ta-p/89572)

Comment: this did not work, i will get an error

Comment: what is the error ? Please send the error details.

Comment: check my edit ....

Comment: there is not Workflow inventory under site settings...

Comment: Check my edited answer above please

Comment: if you find the above answer useful, please remove the negative vote for this answer.